# split rectangle in cells / random coordinates / store in array in FORTRAN

Tags: random, fortran

I would like to split a rectangle in cells. In each cell it should be create a random coordinate (y, z).
[image: Rectangle split in cells]

The wide and height of the rectangle are known (initialW / initalH).
The size of the cells are calculated (dy / dz). 
The numbers, in how many cells the rectangle to be part, are known. (numberCellsY / numberCellsZ)

Here my Code in Fortran to split the rectangle in Cells:[image: Cells]

```fortran
yRVEMin = 0.0
yRVEMax = initialW
dy = ( yRVEMax - yRVEMin ) / numberCellsY         

zRVEMin = 0.0
zRVEMax = initialH
dz = ( zRVEMax - zRVEMin ) / numberCellsZ


do i = 1, numberCellsY 
   yMin(i) = (i-1)*dy
   yMax(i) = i*dy
end do

do j = 1, numberCellsZ 
    zMin(j) = (j-1)*dz
    zMax(j) = j*dz
end do
```

Now I would like to produce a random coordinate in each cell. The problem for me is, to store the coodinates in an array. It does not necessarily all be stored in one array, but as least as possible.

To fill the cells with coordinates it should start at the bottom left cell, go through the rows (y-direction), and after the last cell (numberCellsY) jump a column higher (z-dicrection) and start again by the first cell of the new row at left side. That should be made so long until a prescribed number (nfibers) is reached.

Here a deplorable try to do it:

```fortran
call random_seed
  l = 0
    do k = 1 , nfibers
        if (l < numberCellsY) then
            l = l + 1
        else
            l = 1
        end if
        call random_number(y) 
        fiberCoordY(k) = yMin(l) + y * (yMax(l) - yMin(l))
    end do

n = 0
    do m = 1 , nfibers
        if (n < numberCellsZ) then
            n = n + 1
        else
           n = 1
        end if
        call random_number(z) 
       fiberCoordZ(m) = zMin(n) + z * (zMax(n) - zMin(n))
    end do
```

The output is not what I want! fiberCoordZ should be stay on (zMin(1) / zMax(1) as long as numberCellsY-steps are reached.

The output for following settings:

```
nfibers = 9 
numberCellsY = 3 
numberCellsZ = 3 
initialW = 9.0 
initialH = 9.0
```

My random output for fiberCoordY is:

```
1.768946    3.362770     8.667685     1.898700    5.796713   8.770239       2.463412       3.546694    7.074708
```

and for fiberCoordZ is:

```
2.234807    5.213032     6.762228     2.948657    5.937295    8.649946      0.6795220     4.340364    8.352566
```

In this case the first 3 numbers of fiberCoordz should have a value between 0.0 and 3.0. Than number 4 - 6 a value between 3.0 and 6.0. And number 7 - 9 a value bewtween 6.0 - 9.0.

How can I solve this? If somebody has a solution with a better approach, please post it!

Thanks

Comment: What is the output you get? How should it look like? BTW it is possibl to include pictures in the posts.

Comment: Hey Vladimir, my reputation are under 10. So I can not post pictures.
My random output for fiberCoordY is:

Comment: Never mind, but include how does the result look like and how you want it too look like in the answer at least as a table or description.

Comment: Edit the answer with the information and try to format is so that it is readable. Don't use comments.

Comment: Sorry, I edit my post!

Comment: instead of the if statements with a counter `l`, you could use e.g. `l = mod(k-1,numberCellsY)+1` to compute `l` directly. Also, since `dy` is constant, you don't need to store the offsets in an array and recompute it every time, so I would use e.g. `ysta` as an offset, so `ysta = real(mod(k-1,numberCellsY)[,kind])` and then `fiberCoordY(k) = (yoff + y) * dy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at

```
n = 0
do m = 1 , nfibers
  if (n < numberCellsZ) then
    n = n + 1
  else
   n = 1
  end if
  call random_number(z) 
  fiberCoordZ(m) = zMin(n) + z * (zMax(n) - zMin(n))
end do
```

we see that the z coordinate offset (the bottom cell boundary of interest) is being incremented inappropriately: for each consecutive `nfibers/numberCellsZ` coordinates `n` should be constant.

`n` should be incremented only every numberCellsY iterations, so perhaps a condition like

```
if (MOD(m, numberCellsY).eq.1) n=n+1
```

would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks francescalus! It works fine.

I added a little more for the case that nfibers > numberCellsY*numberCellsZ

```
n=0
do m = 1 , nfibers
       if (MOD(m, numberCellsY).eq.1 .and. (n < numberCellsY))  then
           n=n+1
       end if

       if (MOD(m, numberCellsY*numberCellsZ).eq.1 )  then
           n = 1
       end if

       call random_number(z) 
       fiberCoordZ(m) = zMin(n) + z * (zMax(n) - zMin(n))
end do
```